# Counting the number of files in a directory in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash script where I'm trying to find out the number of files in a directory and perform an addition operation on it as well.

But while doing the same I'm getting the error as follows:

```
admin> ./fileCount.sh
       1
./fileCount.sh: line 6: 22 + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")
```

My script is as shown:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

Var1=22
Var2= ls /stud_data/Input_Data/test3 | grep ".txt" | wc -l 

Var3= $(($Var1 + $Var2))
echo $Var3
```

Can anyone point out where is the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone point out where is the error.

- You shouldn't have spaces around `=`.
- You probably wanted to use command substitution to capture the result in `Var2`.

Try:

```
Var1=22
Var2=$(ls /stud_data/Input_Data/test3 | grep ".txt" | wc -l)

Var3=$(($Var1 + $Var2))
echo $Var3
```

Moreover, you could also say

```
Var3=$((Var1 + Var2))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### A little away

As @devnull already answered to the question *point out where is the error*,

Just some more ideas:

#### General [unix](/questions/tagged/unix)

To make this kind of browsing, there is a **very powerfull** command `find` that let you find recursively, exactly what you're serching for:

```
Var2=`find /stud_data/Input_Data/test3 -name '*.txt' | wc -l`
```

If you won't this to be recursive:

```
Var2=`find /stud_data/Input_Data/test3 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' | wc -l`
```

If you want files only (meaning no symlink, nor directories)

```
Var2=`find /stud_data/Input_Data/test3 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' | wc -l`
```

And so on... Please read the man page: `man find`.

#### Particular [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solutions

As your question stand for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), there is some *bashism* you could use to make this a lot quicker:

```
#!/bin/bash

Var1=22

VarLs=(/stud_data/Input_Data/test3/*.txt)

[ -e $VarLs ] && Var2=${#VarLs[@]} || Var2=0

Var3=$(( Var1 + Var2 ))

echo $Var3

# Uncomment next line to see more about current environment
# set | grep ^Var
```

Where bash expansion will translate `/path/*.txt` in an array containing all filenames matching the jocker form.

If there is no file matching the form, `VarLs` will only contain the jocker form himself.

So the test `-e` will correct this: If the first file of the returned list exist, then assing the number of elements in the list (`${#VarLs[@]}`) to `Var2` else, assign `0` to `Var2`.